# Display empty cell if referencing empty cell (formula)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm working on an excel spreadsheet, and im aiming for a clean interface with almost all cells filled with specific formula.

Ex formula on column V : `=IF(G1=" LNN ","PENDING", "N/A")`

[image: Sample]

What's happening right now is even though there's no data on column G, column V returns one of the "values" on the syntax.

What I want to happen is if a cell in column G doesnt have any data on it, the fields on column V will just be blank / empty.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's a very minor change.

```
=IF(G1="","",IF(G1=" LNN ","PENDING", "N/A"))
```

or

```
=IF(ISBLANK(G1),"",IF(G1=" LNN ","PENDING", "N/A"))
```

---

The `IF` statement is of the syntax `IF(Test,True,False)`. If the condition is true, it returns whatever is in the `True` parameter. In any other case, it returns whatever is in the `False` parameter.